# How to close a socket when using the Executor interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to use Executor interface to create an efficient thread pool when creating new threads for TCP connections. Here's my code:

```
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(20006);  
    Socket client = null;  
    Executor service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();  
    boolean f = true;  
    while(f){  
        client = server.accept();  
        System.out.println("Connection established!");  
        service.execute(new ServerThread(client));  
    }
```

My question is when a thread is inactivated and has been removed from the thread pool, how can I close the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference of the socket to the constructor of `ServerThread`, then at last line of `run()` method, call `socket.close()`:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable // or extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // ...

        socket.close();
    }
}
```